# Coloring points in a funnel plot by study

Tags: plot, metafor

I'm conducting a meta-analysis examining the effects of 3rd grade reading comprehension interventions. I'm analyzing standardized mean differences. I have 20 studies with 54 effects (multiple outcome measures or treatment comparisons/ study).
Given the small sample size and correlated nature of effects, I'm using the following code to do my primary analysis:

```
library(robumeta)
library(clubSandwich)
data (X3rdmetawithcolors)

CEmodel <- rma.mv(yi=adjg,
                  V = var_adjg, #variance
                  random = ~1 | study/eid, 
                  test= "t", 
                  data=X3rdmetaforR2, 
                  method="REML")
summary(CEmodel)
cecf <- coef_test(CEmodel,
                  cluster=X3rdmetaforR2$study_id, 
                  vcov = "CR2")
cecf
```

I also want to do sensitivity analysis. I know that funnel plots and trim and fill procedures are not recommended for multi-level data. However, I would like to generate a funnel plot with individual points colored by study. I have a data frame with colors, study_id, and internal citation which I've merged to my main data frame. and I've tried using the following code to get a funnel plot:

```
res<-rma.mv(yi= adjg, 
      V = var_adjg, 
      random = ~1|study/eid, 
      data=X3rdmetacolor_intcite,
      method="REML")
funnel (res, col=X3rdmetacolor_intcite$color)
```

However, this results in a funnel plot where all of the points are colored in the color of the first study (aquamarine) instead of different colors.

**Any ideas on what I can do? I'd also like to create a legend with showing the color and internal citation.**